# Why can't I download anything from the Market after CSC change?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading, csc

I changed the [CSC](http://ykkfive.blogspot.nl/2011/11/samsung-csc-code-reference.html) to my country and after that, I couldn't download anything from the Market.

**It gives this error: "app name" could not be downloaded due to an error. (-101)**

I tried updating  to Market 3.4.4, cleared the cache, rebooted my phone. Nothing worked. I don't have wifi at home and I get online via free wifi at a local mall. Couldn't download any app for 2 days now (that I've tried after the CSC change) but I'm able to browse.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term. What's "CSC"?

Comment: @AlEverett I found this, appears to be country codes? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=779580

Comment: Also, maybe related: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=787163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing a factory reset, and restoring my personal apps only and not including backups of system data.